# Primus call to nodejs server, primus file not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, primus

I've set up an API with nodejs express for a real-time chat application. For it to be real-time I am using primus but I'm currently stuck at trying to connect primus to my frontend.

I have a folder structure for the whole backend and then another folder structure for my frontend. So they are both separate.

Here I connect the server to Primus

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
const primus = require('../primus/live').go(server);
```

This then goes as you can see to the folder primus with a file live.js

```
//BACKEND

const Primus = require('primus');

let go = (server) => {
    let primus = new Primus(server, {/* options */});
    primus.on('connection', (spark) => {
        console.log('Received spark ');
    });
} 

module.exports.go = go;
```

Now in my frontend, I am trying to call Primus via the script tag

```
//FRONTEND
<script src="http://localhost:3000/primus/live.js"></script>
```

but this just gives me a 404 Not Found error. Also when I just try to connect through this in my browser it doesn't work. So I am unsure what my problem here is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/primus/primus#how-do-i-use-primus-with-express

make sure to call `.listen` on the http server, not the Express server